# Is there a comprehensive list of all (or many) phonological rules (specifically allophonic) of the English language available anywhere online?

Tags: english, phonology, phonetics, phonemes, allophones

It would be very helpful to have for a programming project I'm working on involving grapheme-to-phoneme translation. I've been able to find many rules for phonemes but not too many for allophones.

Comment: Allophonic variation is exceedingly complex and not subject to a single set of rules. Individuals vary a lot, depending on tiredness, emotion, etc. And they vary even more from each other, even in the same speech community. Change communities and you start all over. Allophones are the stuff of sociolinguistic surveys, and correlate more with socioeconomic factors than linguistic ones. Linguists wouldn't mind having a complete list, mind -- but we know how many billions it would cost to develop it.

Comment: Why do you need a list of allophones for grapheme-to-*phoneme* translation? Are you doing speech synthesis?

Answer (score 1):

You ask about allophonic rules for "the English language".  There are no such rules.  There are different allophonic rules for the various dialects of English.  But even collecting a set of rules for some major, more or less standardized English dialect would be problematic, because of linguists' very strong tendency to disagree about the facts, to say nothing of their interpretation.  Probably a fair number of linguists would not even agree that there are such things as allophonic rules (but I do).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in grapheme to *phoneme* translation, you don't need to care at all about allophonic rules. Allophones are not at all reflected in orthography. However, you do need to care about what sense of "phoneme" you are interested in for any translation. People use "phoneme" in many different ways; sometimes they mean "underlying form", and sometimes they mean "phonetic form, but undoing any rules that introduce derived-only segments". The usual example of a derived-only segment for English is aspiration, and another example is the flap [ɾ]. But the flap can come unpredictably either from /t/ or /d/, which means that you can't translate from a surface flap to a specific underlying consonant (thus, under one definition, the flap *is* a phoneme). Whether or not a flap is a segment of underlying representations is completely unclear. Many people like to assert that there are no underlying flaps, but the reasoning for that is usually that you *could* predict a surface flap from some other phoneme, and therefore you can "avoid" having an underlying flap.

I also suggest that you look at the concept of "phonetic implementation", since a lot of what used to be thought of as coming from "allophonic rules" (such as "devoicing of /l/ after /s/") is not the result of a phonological rule, it's a mechanical reflection of how the glottis is opened in producing /s/ in English (which is itself in the realm of "phonetic implementation" and not "phonological rule").

Comment: David Stampe's view is that flap is not a phoneme of English, because language learners follow a principle of least effort, and it's easier for them to assume that every flap they encounter comes from t or d than it is to admit a phoneme flap into their system of phonemes.  (The flapping process is not something that has to be learned -- it's in your realm of "phonetic implementation".)

Comment: How does he account for the difference between "capitalistic" and "militaristic"? Also, what is his underlying representation for "water"?

Comment: @GregLee: what do you mean when you say the flapping process is not something that has to be learned? This seems impossible to me, if we're using an ordinary definition of "learning". Is voicing and flapping alveolar stops an innate process? If so, why does it only show up in specific dialects of English, rather than in all languages?

Comment: In Natural Phonology, innate processes can be suppressed (analogous to constraint domination in OT).

Comment: @sumelic, flapping shows up in some systems and not others because it is suppressed in those systems where it doesn't show up.  Processes are universal in Natural Phonology not in the sense they are everywhere applicable, but in the sense that all humans are born with them -- they are properties of the human articulatory system -- but as children, we learn to constrain them as far as we must to master the pronunciation system of the language we are learning.  Then, when a generation of children fails to acquire a process constraint, we observe a sound change.

Comment: What would David say about  "capitalistic", "militaristic", "water"? I don't know.  If you're making some point, why don't you just say what that is, instead of making me play a guessing game?

Comment: The idea that "saving a phoneme" constitutes a sufficient basis for arbitrary abstract underlying forms was refuted decades ago. Either he admits that aspiration is phonemic, or he admits that flapping is phonemic, because one or the other of those rules is violated in the first pair. Since claiming that there is no underlying flap means that you have to arbitrarily give [waɾɹ̩] the underlying form /watr/ or /wadr/, the obvious solution to his problem is to accept that flap *is* a phoneme.

Comment: I can't speak for David on these issues of detail about phonemes, but I do know that he has argued against identifying phonemic form with a level of derivation, which you seem to be doing.  Speaking only for myself, I can't follow your reasoning at all about "capitalistic" / "militaristic".  Are you assuming that phonological rules and processes make no reference to morphological structure?  I certainly don't assume that. And I have no difficulty making an arbitrary choice of underlying form for "water" -- easiest thing in the world.  I'll make it a /t/.